# How to change the shape of a switch in android

Tags: android, android-switch

I created a layout file using a switch. Now I want to change shape of its selector.Also I want to remove text on this switch.

Currently it has a rectangular shape . I want to change it to a circular shape.

[image: This is my requirement]

This is my layout file ,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_remind_me"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.pvt.RemindMeActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="3">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/remind_me_head_txt"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:text="Example one"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="120dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <Switch
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:showText="false"
                android:id="@+id/remind_me_switch"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:id="@+id/remind_me_list_img"
                android:src="@drawable/list_menu" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/remind_me_title_txt"
            android:text="Sample Head"
            android:textSize="12sp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/remind_me_content_txt"
            android:text="Content"
            android:textSize="12sp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Currently I have no idea about how to achieve this.

Can we change the shape of a switch ? Is it possible ?

Comment: you can try https://github.com/kyleduo/SwitchButton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use any shapes and styles u like for switch in android
This library will help u a lot
[SwitchButton](https://github.com/kyleduo/SwitchButton)

Answer (score 5):

These shape changes according to devices, for instance it will appear rectangular in `Redmi Note` and circular in `Moto` .

Although, In order to achieve this you can have a toggle implementation such as below : 
Having three styles :

- offToggle ( `Style Off` )
- onToggle ( `Style On` )
- custom_toggle ( `Style Custom Toggle` )

**Style Off**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval"
    android:visible="true">
    <solid android:color="@android:color/holo_blue_dark" />
</shape>
```

**Style On**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval"
    android:visible="true">
    <solid android:color="@android:color/black" />
</shape>
```

Now the collective style which we will use in our layout **Style Custom Toggle**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/offToggle" android:state_enabled="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/onToggle" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/onToggle" android:state_checked="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/onToggle" android:state_focused="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/offToggle"/>
</selector>
```

Now just use this style in your layout, for instance :

```
<ToggleButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textOn=""
    android:textOff=""
    android:background="@drawable/custom_toggle" />
```

**Tip** : To remove text from switch/Toggle use `android:textOn=""` `android:textOff=""` .